# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to copy support app

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-support-library

I'm trying to set up a tabbed interface for [my application](https://github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker/tree/add-tabs). I opened up the `Support13Demos` project distributed with the ADT. I am able to compile and run it. In order to work from it, I [created a new project](https://github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker/tree/add-tabs/) with a  `com.example.android.supportv13.app` package and [copied the appropriate files](https://github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker/tree/add-tabs/src/com/example/android/supportv13/app) into it.

Then I copied over the referenced layouts and strings. All of my compilation errors are gone, but the application starts and immediately crashes with the error: `Could not find class 'com.example.android.supportv13.app.ActionBarTabsPager$TabsAdapter', referenced from method com.example.android.supportv13.app.ActionBarTabsPager.onCreate`.

The class [`ActionBarTabsPager` does include a class `TabsAdapter`](https://github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker/blob/add-tabs/src/com/example/android/supportv13/app/ActionBarTabsPager.java).

```
public class ActionBarTabsPager extends Activity {
  … 
  public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener { … }
}
```

I have tried cleaning the project and it didn't help. Private Libraries are also enabled.

Comment: did you add the support lib to your build path? Also try cleaning your project, sometimes eclipse gets wonky and cleaning will fix issues like this.

Comment: Make sure option Private Libraries is enabled under Build Path-> Order and Export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `android-support-v13.jar` to the exports and removed `Android Private Libraries`.

Answer (score 0):

i cant speak english well ,hope i can help u.
first right-click on your project--BuildPath--ConfigureBuildPath.
and then choose Order And ExPort
maybe some jar you need but you have not choose.
here's two picture(before modified and after modified)
before:http://img.my.csdn.net/uploads/201212/04/1354602396_3168.jpg;
after:http://img.my.csdn.net/uploads/201212/04/1354602436_2486.jpg